# How to make limits stay the same even when changing sizes/resolutions?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

This part of the script limits movement on x and y so the camera can't go outside of the game scene and it works on my 2d ortographic camera.

```
var pos = transform.position;
transform.position = new Vector2(
Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, xPanMax, xPanMin), 
Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, yPanMax, yPanMin));
```

When I change the screen size the limits are all off and I have to readjust the numbers for it not to leave the games boundaries or being able to pan around the whole scene.

Is there any way to change this code so the limits stay the same even when changing sizes/resolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Cinemachine. It has dynamic understanding of the frame and scene and view.

You can learn much more about it here:https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.1/manual/index.html

Cinemachine is a free addon package for 2018.1 and up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I looked cinemachine up, but the moment I add a cinemachine 2d camera, my script stops working until i disable the camera again. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You'll have to rewrite your script to operate on vcams, the Cinemachine variation of cameras. It's not a straight plugin and go, you'll need to learn a bit about the ways Cinemachine works, and how it overcomes the (massive) limitations of the Unity camera. Well worth it, because you'll find all sorts of things you can do with Cinemachine that are really easy to do with it, because it's designed to be a camera system. It is, IMNSHO, the most essential thing to add into Unity.